# Postgres Join on case insensitive text field

Tags: postgresql

I have to perform a left join on two string in a case-insensitive way.

This is case-sensitive (176ms)

```
SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON b.text = a.text
```

I've tried a few options but are too slow.

**Option 1** (40000ms)

```
WITH upper_b AS (
  SELECT UPPER(text) FROM b
), upper_a AS (
  SELECT UPPER(text) FROM a
)

SELECT * FROM upper_a LEFT JOIN upper_b ON upper_b.text = upper_a.text
```

**Option 2** (60000ms)

```
SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON UPPER(b.text) = UPPER(a.text)
```

Comment: I believe there is advice on how to post performace questions somewhere in the group's help docs. At the very least you're going to have to say what type the columns are, whether you are using a case-insensitive collation and what indexes you have (obviously if you don't have an index on `UPPER(xxx.text)` all the planner can do is scan both the tables - possibly spilling a sort to disk or some such)

Comment: Please see [mcve],